# How can I set back to first view controller by navigation controller in code in present without segue?

Tags: ios, swift

I have in my project tow view controller and I linked the first VC with navigation controller but the problem is : I used present to go to second VC (that mean I didn't use segue) ... how can I set back to first VC in navigation Controller by code (without segue) .

picture from my storyboard
[image: my storyboard]
my code :

```
let storyboard = self.storyboard
let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contact_detail") as! ViewController2
viewcontroller.arr2 = arr
present(viewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `pushViewController`

```
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MyViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `dismiss` method it will work.

> Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view controller. **(Apple Docs)**

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I know but Im didn't need this a way

Comment: @ahmedasi if you don't need this way, which way you need?

Comment: @canister_exister I solved this by using :              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MyViewController, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting a `viewcontroller` with `present` method, you can dismiss it with `dismiss` method.

If you are adding any view controller with `push` method then only it will get added to your navigation stack and you can remove it by calling `popviewcontroller` on it's `back` action.

Here, you are presenting a `viewcontroller`, hence it will not get added to your first navigation stack and you can not remove it with `pop` action on click of back.

If you are looking for a `back` button like feature on presented view controller, you can add a `back` button in `toolbar`, `dismiss` a `viewcontroller` on back button action, and can animate it like a popnavigation while dismissing.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UINavigationController { 
     public func removeViewController(classes : [String]) {
           var vcs = [UIViewControllers]()
           for viewController in self.viewControllers {
               let name = viewController.className
               if !classes.contains(name) {
                    vcs.append(viewController)
                }
           }
           if classes.count < vcs.count {
               self.viewControllers = vcs
           }
    }
}
```

now think you have 4 viewControllers , A, B, C, D, you want to remove B and C and Move Back To A

In D's View Controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //your works
   let viewControllersToRemove = [String(describing: type(of:B)), String(describing: type(of:C))]
   navigationController.removeViewControoler(classes : viewControllersToRemove)
}
```